# kubernetes dashboard is not accessible from outside

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

I have installed and configure Kubernates in my Ubuntu virtual machine

Reference: [Document Link](https://www.edureka.co/blog/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu)

Started kubernetes proxy using below command

```
kubectl proxy --address='0.0.0.0'
```

I'm able to access my dashboard using http://localhost:8001 link on localhost when I'm trying to access the dashboard from outside using http://192.168.33.30:8001/ link getting following Error

```
<h3>Unauthorized</h3>
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Hi. Have you tried this?:kubectl proxy --address='localhost' --accept-hosts='^.*$' --port=8001

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, It works using Command: `kubectl proxy --address='0.0.0.0' --accept-hosts='^.*$' --port=8001` and I'm able to access 
kubernetes dashboard from outside but not able to login using provided token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works using below command:

```
kubectl proxy --address='0.0.0.0' --accept-hosts='^.*$' --port=8001
```

After this, I am able to access the Kubernetes dashboard outside using VM IP address

Comment: Can you please explain this solution.Why simply kubectl proxy doesn't work.Every online document only mentions about that only.

Comment: I am a bit late to answer Ratish Bansal but I found this page with this problem. Ashwani has a great solution which worked for me, but I also wanted to understand what it means. 

The docs are here https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#proxy

The key here is --accept-hosts='^.*$' which is a regular expression indicating which hosts can access this endpoint. 
Using Ashwani's solution will allow anybody who can reach that endpoint to access the data there. 

You probably want to change this if you need a secure application.

Comment: For anyone still having the problem; issue the same command with sudo. It will help you access the dashboard outside VM.